# IntelliJ Glassfish5 JAX-RS Path not working

Tags: intellij-idea, jersey, jax-rs

I have a problem for days now. 
I made it that my server is working and now I can't get the paths to work.

I want to run a simple Java Class

```
package org.eberle.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


@Path("/cab")
public class CabRequestHandler {

    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    public Response addRequest(
            @FormParam("TaxiNr") int cabNumber ,
            @FormParam("StartAdresse") String startAddress,
            @FormParam("EndAdresse") String endAddress){

        return Response.status(200)
                .entity("addRequest is called, TaxiNr : " + cabNumber + ", StartAddresse : " + startAddress + ", Endadresse" + endAddress)
                .build();
    }

}
```

I am running the deploy T4:war exploded on the custom text root in the glassfish server settings.

```
localhost:8081/root
```

This is working and it shows my index.jsp

But the next problem is, that I don't know how to configure the `web.xml`. I tried so many `web.xml` from here and the internet and they are all not working for me.
When I try to open up my path `/root/cab/add` it says Error 404.

Can someone help me please with a working web.xml.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I assume this is to run on tomcat, please share your `web.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `/root` is the context of your app, your **web.xml** should probably look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>

        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.eberle.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This way all the calls to `/root/` should be handled by Jersey

Answer (score -1):

Tried Bentaye solution but not working (probably because I used jakarta.ws.rs.* instead of javax.ws.rs). But his solution is very similar to the one I found: [Why am I getting 404 error Message "Not Found" on get request for my jersey rest service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66886095/why-am-i-getting-404-error-message-not-found-on-get-request-for-my-jersey-rest).

EDITED >>>>
Bentaye solution is correct, I tested it on GlassFish 5.1.

The example given in the linked question is very clear and easy to replicate on Glassfish 5.1 installation.
This is the web.xml I propose:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>sp-core</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.eberle.rest.HelloApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>restServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the new application class:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/*")
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        System.out.println("sono dentro getClasses");
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(CabRequestHandler.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

P.S. The linked question is not the same of this one because this question is about GlassFish 5 and the other is about Jersy: closing this one has no sense.  I think that having more than one solution can help and I think that having a related link to follow is better than having nothing. For me does not matter the form but to help someone else who are struggling for a solution like I did.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.

Comment: Also please make sure that any answer or duplicate proposal provides a solution to the question at the top of this page - not only to a similar but non-identical problem you had.

Comment: Comments are used to ask for clarifications, noy for proposing an alternate solution. Proposed question  is not a duplicate. I woukd be grateful if there was also avresponse like mine, I would have spent less time searching for another solution for me. I will retry Bentaye solution if it suits for my problem

Comment: Alternate solutions which are answers to questions which are basically asking the same, should be proposed by pointing them out as duplicate. You have the privilege needed for that, please use it. If it is not the same question please tailor the answer to fit this one. Only linking, without giving it as a duplicate is not the right way.